# "A fire in Chursoo village in Jammu and Kashmir's Awantipora" is this correct grammar?

Tags: prepositions, noun-phrases

I cannot work out if "a fire in Chursoo village in Jammu and Kashmir's Awantipora" is grammatically correct in UK English grammar.

The text is copied from an English language newspaper in India.

Should it be "a fire in the village of Chursoo in Jammu and Kashmir's Awantipora"?

The meaning is clear in the original, I'm just not sure if it is grammatically correct.

Comment: The news media use this kind of possessive all the time in order to cram more information into a headline or sentence. It's standard practice but not necessarily a good idea outside the news media.

Comment: Often titles are not complete sentences. So it's tough to make them grammatically correct to start.

Comment: Thank you.  This is in body text, not a headline, which is why I got a bit confused if it was acceptable or not. I appreciate there are some differences between Indian English and UK English and I just wondered how acceptable this sentence is in UK English.  I think it should be changed to "a fire in the village of..." to meet UK English grammar rules. I just want to know if this kind of possessive can pass in UK English.